# writing pandas data frame to existing workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to save a data frame to the second sheet of a file but I can't do that and I don't know why.

```
yfile = openpyxl.load_workbook(new_file, data_only=True) 
ws = yfile.worksheets[0] 
sheet2 = yfile.create_sheet() 
ws2 = yfile.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet").title = "Analysis" 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(yfile, engine='xlsxwriter') 
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Analysis') 
writer.save()
yfile.save(new_file)
```

I have created the sheet 'Analysis' but when I save in it I received the following response: "AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'write'"

What I have to modify?

Comment: One issue is that you are creating `yfile` as an `openpyxl` objectand then passing it to `pd.ExcelWriter` but telling it that it should use the `xlsxwriter` engine. These two objects are incompatible so that isn't going to work. However, I don't know if it will work even with an openpyxl object and engine created in this way.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `append_df_to_excel()` helper function, which is [defined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046/5741205):

Demo:

```
In [127]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3), columns=list('abc'))

In [128]: df
Out[128]:
          a         b         c
0  0.597353  0.770586  0.671231
1  0.628605  0.161283  0.397493
2  0.476206  0.701582  0.476809
3  0.045590  0.302834  0.857033
4  0.414820  0.478016  0.563258

In [129]: df.to_excel(filename)

In [130]: append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name="Sheet2", startrow=1, startcol=1)

In [131]: append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name="Sheet3", index=False)

In [132]: append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name="Sheet1", startcol=2, index=False)
```

---

Result:

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Sheet3:

[image]

PS tested using the following versions:

- python: 3.6.4
- pandas: 0.22.0
- openpyxl: 2.4.10

Comment: oh man, I was just replicating your code thinking you finally helped me resolve this issue but when I ran the thing, it creates new sheets adding a 1 at the end of the name instead of replacing the old ones with new data, what can I do to fix that?

Comment: @mkheifetz, do you want to replace existing sheet or add data to the end of it?

Comment: looks like I figured it out already based on another post, thank you regardless

Comment: Has anyone fixed The helper to replace Sheet_1 but no other sheet? Thanks

Comment: @Tinkinc, i'm not sure i understand you... What exactly do you mean?

Comment: The helper inserts the df into sheet 1. I am looking to just replace sheet 1 not continuously append it. While preserving the actual excel file/tabs if they exist. thanks

Comment: @Tinkinc, did you try to specify `startrow=0`?

Comment: @MaxU. Yes, but it seems it just slides down the data I am trying to reprocess-all from that tab... thoughts? and thank you for the help

Comment: @Tinkinc, i've slightly modified the helper function, so it will start writing from the first line,.... BUT it will not delete data from existing cells - it'll simply overwrite first N lines where `N` - is the # of rows in your DataFrame

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167581/discussion-between-tinkinc-and-maxu).

Comment: @Tinkinc, i've added `truncate_sheet` option ;-)

Comment: Well written method.
Just one more thing. As i am trying to insert a plot created by matplotlib, can you please tell me how do I insert an image in the excel file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use such way as below.
It writes dataframe  to an excel-file row by row.

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
filename = r'some_file.xlsx'
df = some_dataframe

wb = load_workbook(filename)
if 'sh2' in wb.sheetnames:#to check whether sheet you need already exists
    ws = wb['sh2']
else:
    ws = wb.active
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
wb.save(filename)
```

Comment: I've searched all internet and only this solution worked! Other ones worked in Jupyter but not in Shell for me (corrupting excel file) and this one does. Thanks!