# How to add sheet to many excel file without overwriting using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to write sheets to excel file(some of them are existing, but others no)
I use `df.groupby('mail').apply(lambda g: g.to_excel(str(g.name) + '.xlsx'), 'sheet1')`
I group data from exel file and want to divide it to a lot of little with different `mail`. I still have 3 `df` and I want to group it with `mail` and also add to others `sheet` to files. 
How can I do it to 50 `mail` at the same time without overwriting?

Comment: you may want to check [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447758/writing-pandas-data-frame-to-existing-workbook/36450435#36450435)

Comment: @MaxU, but if I have a lot of file? how can i do this?