# How do I insert a value in Excel using python

Tags: python, excel

a very straightforward task in VBA but am not sure how do I perform in python.
Hypothetically if I have an excel called 'excel.xlsm', tab name is 'tabA' and I want to insert a value in cell D15, how do I do that in python?

Comment: This question has a lot of answers if searched on Google. Please do some research before asking on SO community.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert row into Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299364/insert-row-into-excel-spreadsheet-using-openpyxl-in-python)

Comment: @Mayank Porwal - thanks mate that was useful as well.

Comment: @Abhay salvi - never heard of google, can you send me the link plz!

Comment: Yeah sure @PrasKam ✌. Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805677/write-values-to-a-particular-cell-in-a-sheet-in-pandas-in-python

Comment: @Abhaysalvi  - thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a library called openpyxl for that:

```
import openpyxl

workbook=openpyxls.load_workbook(path)
worksheet= workbook.get_sheet_by_name('tabA')
worksheet['D15']='Whatever you want to put in D15'
```

Enjoy and read up on openpyxl for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't edit [Tomfus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13362279/tomfus)'s answer.  To save you excel file after changes you made (otherwise you won't see updates in file). Run `workbook.save('file path of your excel')`

NOT: File path could be same file path/name that you used to open if you don't want to create copy. It will overwrite automatically