# Get length of dataframe as it appears in Excel (eg. including any column levels)

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

**EDIT: Essentially I need a method compatible with single level column indexes and MultiIndex columns which will return the integer number of levels in the columns.**

I am writing multiple DataFrames out to Excel on a single sheet, and would like to move the `start_row` on to avoid overwriting any data.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=[list('ABCD'), list('EFGH')])
print(len(df)
```

`len(df)` will return 10; **how can I also get the index levels included, so that the return value is 12?**

`len(df.columns.levels)` will only work if the columns are a multi-index. This applies for some of my dataframes but not all. They are a mix of single level and multiindex.

Is a `try except` block the best approach (catching AttributeError for the single level dataframes), or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: How about using something like `length = len(df) + len(df.columns.levshape)`?

Comment: If I haven't misunderstood, this might solve your problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas)

Comment: @screenpaver .levshape is new to me but raises AttributeError for non-MultiIndex columns.

Comment: @MateoRod my concern is knowing the correct startrow after I have written out the dataframe. This will depend on the number of column levels.

Essentially I need a method compatible with single level column indexes and MultiIndex columns which will return the integer number of levels in the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html) mentions an attribute *nlevels* you could use.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=[list('ABCD'), list('EFGH')])
print(df1.columns)
print(df1.columns.nlevels)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
print(df2.columns)
print(df2.columns.nlevels)
```

gives

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']],
       labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
2
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
1
```

which should answer you question concerning the number of lines to move.