# Creating a single dataframe from files with similar name stored at different directories in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder with multiple sub-folders each named with the date it was created e.g:- "18-07-2018".

Path to folder from root :- "/Analytics/Predictive_Analysis/"

There are multiple files inside each of these sub folders.
Each of these sub-folders contains an excel sheet with the same name "activity_log_dtl" having equal number of columns.

I intend to create a  single dataframe using the data from  all "activity_log_dtl" excel sheets.
I can proceed with creating separate dataframes for each  "activity_log_dtl" excel and then merging/concating them into a single dataframe.
But I intend to create a single dataframe without the need to create diferent dataframes and then merging them.

Please suggest.

Comment: What's *the problem* with reading separate dataframes and then combining?

Comment: Since I am working with live data(a new folder each day),so if I read from separate data-frame,I have to create a new data-frame to access the current day's data everytime. This is the only problem I see and I want to bypass it.

Comment: See [Append existing excel sheet with new dataframe using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas).