# Pandas to excel: append a dataframe to an excel sheet with existing data w/o overwritting

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This question has been asked but I tried every solution and it still overwrite what I already have in my sheet. What I have tried:
`writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/home/viktor/Downloads/kpi_report_current.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df_kpi.to_excel(writer, index=True)
writer.save()`

But it overwrite the dataframe that I previously exported to the excel sheet...I tried every solution on the following page:[How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas)

To be more precise, I tried the following: 
from openpyxl import load_workbook

```
book = load_workbook('/home/viktor/Downloads/kpi_report_current.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/home/viktor/Downloads/kpi_report_current.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df_kpi.to_excel(writer)

writer.save()
```

Which load the existing data on the excel sheet, but it is still overwritting it...

Any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try loading the excel to a dataframe append the new data and then save it to excel again?

Comment: Just open existing worksheet using openpyxl module and write data row by row and close file.      Try This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas

Comment: @SurajM can you show me? I am stuck right now..

Comment: Example is given in link that I provided above...Check  `def append_df_to_excel` function.

Comment: Yes thanks I did not read everything! Thanks