# Python Pandas 'Dataframe.to_excel' Save Data Problem

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I develop data analysis app with Python.
The data in the file is deleted when I add data to it again when I do df.to_excel.
How can I add new data to the excel file while preserving other data
Thanks,

sorry for my bad english

I used This code for add data

```
def ageGroup(city,age,period):
 ....
 df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
 ...

for i in range(len(city_list)):
for j in range(len(age_list_)):
    ageGroup(city_list[i], age_list_[j], 22)
```

Comment: The helper function in the first answer here will do everyhing you want and more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at these parameters from the `to_excel` method ?

```
startrow : int, default 0
Upper left cell row to dump data frame.

startcol : int, default 0
Upper left cell column to dump data frame.
```

You could open your data, get the length of it, and write more starting at the length of your data +1.

Comment: This is not happening either.
I did startrow = 0 and I increased the startrow variable len (df) +1 in each loop.
Didn't add under