# Append pandas dataframe to excelsheet, not overwrite it

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to append the contents of a panda dataframe `df` to an excelsheet.

This is what I did;

```
df.to_excel(excel_writer="target.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet_1")
```

The problem with this code is that it overwrites `target.xlsx`. I lost all my old data in `target.xlsx` as a result. What I want the code to do is to append, not overwrite the excel sheet.

I am using python 3.7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append existing excel sheet with new dataframe using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas)

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to read all data from your excel file, combine it in python and then write it back to excel?

Comment: @Sosel, My excel sheet has several other worksheets unrelated to the dataframe.

Comment: @user781486 is this related to your question? [How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas)

Comment: This might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412725/how-do-you-append-a-new-row-in-an-excisting-excel-file-using-python-with-multipl/61436236#61436236

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47740262/9375102) answer by MaxU worked for me when I did more excel & python stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('target.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:  
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet_1')
```

Source: [Pandas Dataframe to Excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

Comment: This is probably the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way to do this is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet() # a created excel sheet

array = pd.read_csv('array.csv')
array = array.tolist()

row = 0

for col, data in enumerate(array):
    worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)

workbook.close()
```

Here is the xlsxwriter [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to append a new sheet, here's your answer.

```
import pandas as pd

# Open the existing excel file with all sheets
df_dict = pd.read_excel('target.xlsx',sheet_name=None)

with pd.ExcelWriter(fp) as writer:

     # Save the original sheets
     for sheet in df_dict:
          df[sheet].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)

     # If the new sheet name doesn't exist, append it
     if 'sheet_1' not in df_dict:
          df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet_1')
```

Answer (score 3):

Load 'target.xlsx' in target_df.
Then

```
new_df = target_df.append(df)
```

It should work fine I guess. Then save it back as 'target.xlsx'.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply read the data stored in target.xlsx and store it in a data frame. Now, using `pandas` `concat()` method, you can merge the two data frames (new data frame and old data frame) and finally store them in the same excel file.

Code Snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
old_df = pd.read_excel('target.xlsx')  
frames = [old_df, new_df]
result = pd.concat(frames)
result.to_excel("target.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet_1", index=False)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('target.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = load_workbook('target.xlsx')
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name="sheet_1")
writer.save()
```