# Panda's ExcelWriter append mode not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't understand why `mode='a'` or even `mode='w'` is not working.
My code is :

```
file = "Data_Complet.xlsx"
df1 = pd.read_excel(file, encoding='utf-8')
df_transfo = DataFrame(df1, columns = ['DATE','Nb'])
print(df_transfo)
with ExcelWriter(path="Data_Complet.xlsx", mode='a') as writer:
    df_transfo.to_excel(writer)
```

The result is:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'.

I am using Spyder.

Comment: i can't replicate your error, what is your pandas version? And have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas

Comment: check with pandas version, mode argument is in pandas from 0.24.0 version afterward

Comment: That's right, my version is 0.21, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I keep coming to this question and forget what I did! So, I'm adding the code for it.

As stated in the comments, you need to have `pandas` version greater than `0.24.0`.
Just run

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```