# Dataframe to excel sheet not working as expected

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with certain variables. When I print the dataframe within the loop, I see all the different rows of data. But when I try to write this data into a spreadsheet on Excel, only the last row is written.

```
file1r = open("Catastrophe Reinsurance.txt","r")
lines_counter_18 = 1
for line in file1r:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    if lines_counter_18 > 9:
       year = line[0:4]
       year_2013 = line[7:18]
       year_2014 = line[21:32]
       year_2015 = line[35:46]
       year_2016 = line[49:60]
       year_2017 = line[63:74]
       year_2018 = line[77:88]
       df_1r = pd.DataFrame({'year':year,'year_2013':year_2013,'year_2014':year_2014,'year_2015':year_2015,'year_2016':year_2016,'year_2017':year_2017,'year_2018':year_2018},index=[0])
       #print(df_1r)
    lines_counter_18 += 1
    df_1r.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Catastrophe Reinsurance',index=True)
```

I define the writer outside of the loop as :
`writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')`

I save the workbook outside of the loop as well. The looping logic does not seem to work since only the last row is written to the sheet. Am I missing something?

Comment: this code does not execute, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Answer (score 0):

`to_excel` will overwrite the file so you're only getting the `df_1r` from the last iteration. There are ways to append to an excel sheet rather than overwrite ([Append existing excel sheet with new dataframe using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas)) but if you're not worried about running out of memory it's much simpler to build a single data frame by appending rows to your dataframe within the loop (see [pandas append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)) and then write the whole dataframe to the excel file once outside of the loop.

Also, as your loop currently stands you will be creating duplicate rows when `lines_counter_18` is less than 9 (`df_1r` will exist from the previous iteration in the loop and get written again).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) each data frame to a one final data frame and save.otherwise each `df_1r` will overwrite the previous data frame.

```
file1r = open("Catastrophe Reinsurance.txt","r")
lines_counter_18 = 1
final = pd.DataFrame()
for line in file1r:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    if lines_counter_18 > 9:
       year = line[0:4]
       year_2013 = line[7:18]
       year_2014 = line[21:32]
       year_2015 = line[35:46]
       year_2016 = line[49:60]
       year_2017 = line[63:74]
       year_2018 = line[77:88]
       df_1r = pd.DataFrame({'year':year,'year_2013':year_2013,'year_2014':year_2014,'year_2015':year_2015,'year_2016':year_2016,'year_2017':year_2017,'year_2018':year_2018},index=[0])
       #print(df_1r)
    final = pd.concat([final,df_1r])
    lines_counter_18 += 1

final.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Catastrophe Reinsurance',index=True)
```