# How to Update df to existing excel file with python

Tags: python

I have existing excel file for updated finished e_mail.I need to update any detail to existing excel.This's my existing excel file.It have only header Like This:
[image]

This's my output.It's split two excel files.Like this.

[image]

In Excel file it show detail like this:

[image]

I want output to update detail to existing excel file. like this:

[image]

This's my python code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
import time
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl
today = datetime.today().strftime('%d%m%Y')
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("3.1done_FPA")
finishbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("4.finished")
outlook = inbox.Items
mail = outlook.GetLast()

filename = "R:/ReportAFS/PaymentOutlookForm/PaymentOutlookForm_"+str(today)+".xlsx"

for mail in reversed(outlook):
    subject = mail.Subject

    df = pd.read_excel("R:/veerachai/Invoice_form/copy_file/b'"+str(subject)+"'"+"/"+"b'"+str(subject)+"'.xlsm",sheet_name ='PaymentOutlookForm')

    directory = 'R:/ReportAFS/PaymentOutlookForm'
    file = 'PaymentOutlookForm_'+str(today)+'_'+str(subject)+'.xlsx'

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    df.to_excel(os.path.join(directory, file),index = False)

    time.sleep(1)
    mail.Move(finishbox)
    print(str(mail.Subject)+ ' working success.')
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel can open and work with `.csv` files quite easily. You can convert the current Excel file to `.csv` and then work easily with it using `pandas`. It offers the `to_csv()` method with different `modes` which is perfect for what you need. Given that you just want to append a row to an already existing `.csv`, you can just call the `to_csv()` method specifying the `a` mode parameter and setting the `header` to `False` (since we don't want to re-write the header every time).

```
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

If you want to work directly with Excel files (without converting to `.csv`), you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas).