# How to append dataframe to xlsx file without loading workbook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm working with slightly big data and i need to write this data to an xlsx file. Sometimes the size of this files can be 15GB. I have a python code that gets data as dataframes and writes data to excel continuously so i need to write data to an existing excel and the existing sheet. I was using 'openpyxl'.
There are two problems that I faced while working with that library.

1. Firstly to append an existing excel it needs to load workbook which is an impossible thing for me because of the data size. I must use
   the lowest RAM I can use.  -
2. Secondly this lib is useful only writing
   to the different sheets. When I'm trying to write data to same sheet
   even if I give the 'startrow' for the saving process it deletes the
   old data and writes new one starting from that row.

I already tried the solution available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas) to address my problem but it doesn't fit my requirements.

Do you have any idea how I can do this?.

Comment: at the risk of sounding like a cliche SO answer, you should probably consider switching to a database and generating ondemand excel reports, the file sizes you're discussing just aren't manageable in the paradigm you're working under right now

Comment: I know this data is unmanageable with this view. The project will work with a database but due to the management issues right now i need to go with this solution.