# Pages are deleted after saving to an Excel file, how to fix it? Used the pandas library

Tags: python, excel, pandas

After saving, all sheets in the Excel file are deleted except for the one to which I wrote new data, how to fix it?

```
def teach_add_3():
with pd.ExcelWriter('bd1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='teachers')
    teacher = input("Enter teacher: ")
    subject = input("Enter subject: ")
    df.loc[index, 'Преподаватели'] = teacher
    df.loc[index, 'Предметы'] = subject
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='teachers')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append existing excel sheet with new dataframe using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas)

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54188876/9375102) answer is more appropriate if your using a newer pandas version.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, we would have open our own ExcelWriter with the "append" mode like this:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('bd1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:  
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='teachers')
```

Make sure to install the `openpyxl` module.

```sh
pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!

Comment: Try specifying the engine. I updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: I changed the code, can you see if it is correct or not?

Comment: The last line of your code should be `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='teachers')`, so delete the line and replace it with that.

Comment: NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: You accidentally deleted this piece of code: `df = pd.read_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers') `

Comment: after launch, a new sheet is created with the name teacher1 and new data is added there, but nothing has changed in the old one.