# openpyxl load_workbook() on a legit .xlsx file leads to a zipfile.BadZipFile error

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

What I was trying to do is appening dataframe data to an existing legit excel file.
I used load_workbook() function from openpyxl, but it systematically returns an error.
Here is some code that crashes on my machine:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

report_path = root_folder + '\\log_report.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(report_path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = load_workbook(report_path)
writer.close()
```

Here, log_report.xlsx already exists and have been created through pandas .to_excel().
Before opening with openpyxl load_workbook(), it is possible to open it, to edit it and do anything MS Excel allows.
I got the following error returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/failsafe_counter/main.py", line 419, in <module>
    writer.book = load_workbook(report_path)
  File "D:\failsafe_counter\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "D:\failsafe_counter\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "D:\failsafe_counter\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1336, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Important aspect of that is this operation left the initial excel file corrupted, and impossible to open again.

Initial file is a legit zipfile (verified through renaming the xlsx into a .zip). Once the little code above returns the error, it turns the Excel file into an empty archive (verified through the same process).

I employed such functions with success on my previous laptop (under windows 7) but since I migrated under windows 10 I'm not able to use them anymore. Both of them were running python 3.8.

Is there any known issue about openpyxl load_workbook() on some configs?
Do you have any idea how to fix this, or any workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to replicate the problem. It is `pandas` related. Everything works just fine up to pandas 1.1.5
In pandas 1.2.0 they did [some changes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html)

At the time when you instantiate `pd.ExcelWriter` with

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(report_path, engine='openpyxl')`
```

it creates empty file with size 0 bytes and overwrites the existing file  and then you get error when try to load it. It is not `openpyxl` related, because with latest version of `openpyxl` it works fine with pandas 1.1.5.

The solution - specify `mode='a'`, change the above line to

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(report_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
```

Alternatively - look at @CharlieClark solution or [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221655/4046632) where they loads the file before instantiating the `pd.ExcelWriter`..

Comment: I had exact same issue, moving from old laptop to new laptop.. same OS (Windows 10) but different Pandas package version.  The "mode = 'a'" solved the issue.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The exception is quite clear: openpyxl cannot read the file because it is **not** a zipfile.

`pd.ExcelWriter(report_path, engine='openpyxl')` creates a new file but as this is a completely empty file, openpyxl cannot load it. If you want to work with a file in both Pandas an openpyxl, you have to create a "book" object.

```py
wb = load_workbook(report_path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(report_path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = wb
```

Comment: Issue is that it is a legit xlsx file and thus a legit archive. It can be opened without any issue in excel until I first try to access it through load_workbook(). It's like load_workbook itself corrupts the xlsx file. On top of that, same initial file accessed on my older machine through the same method didn't lead to any error.

Comment: Just because Excel can open it, does not mean it is a legitimate zipfile. For example, it might be encrypted.

Comment: You're right. So I renamed the excel file before opening it with openpyxl by adding a .zip and I've been able to open it. Once I run the little code on it and thus open it with openpyxl, it appears it became an empty zip. Indeed it seems that the load_workbook() function itself causes trouble on my setup for some reasons. I edited my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that problem occour when file is *internal* in company domain (not public).

Comment: I have opened file manually and change the access label to public