# Property 'sheets' of 'OpenpyxlWriter' object has no setter using pandas and openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, setter

This code used to get a xlsx file and write over it, but after updating from pandas 1.1.5 to 1.5.1 I got `zipfile.badzipfile file is not a zip file`

Then I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66472617/13274766) that after pandas 1.2.0 the `pd.ExcelWriter(report_path, engine='openpyxl')` creates a new file but as this is a completely empty file, openpyxl cannot load it.

Knowing that, I changed the code to this one, but now I'm getting `AttributeError: property 'sheets' of 'OpenpyxlWriter' object has no setter`. How should I handle this?

```
book = load_workbook('Resultados.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Resultados.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

    reader = pd.read_excel(r'Resultados.xlsx')

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_)
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader) + 1)

    writer.close()
```

Comment: You may have to rework your code a bit more. See the examples in the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: I'v read many things, saddly still not able to do this

Comment: You overwrite the file and then try to read from it before you have stored anything in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TLDR

- Use `.update` to modify `writer.sheets`
- Rearrange the order of your script to get it working

```py
# run before initializing the ExcelWriter
reader = pd.read_excel("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")

book = load_workbook("Resultados.xlsx")

# use `with` to avoid other exceptions
with pd.ExcelWriter("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets.update(dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets))

    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader)+1)
```

## Details

Recreating your problem with some fake data

```py
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # make some random data
    np.random.seed(0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(5, 5)))

    # this makes an existing file
    with pd.ExcelWriter("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
        df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer)

    # make new random data
    np.random.seed(1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(5, 5)))

    # what you tried...
    book = load_workbook("Resultados.xlsx")
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

    reader = pd.read_excel("Resultados.xlsx")

    # skipping this step as we defined `df` differently
    # df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_)
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader)+1)

    writer.close()
```

We get the same error plus a `FutureWarning`

```
...\StackOverflow\answer.py:23: FutureWarning: Setting the `book` attribute is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected or corrupted results and will be removed in a future version
  writer.book = book
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\StackOverflow\answer.py", line 24, in <module>
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'sheets'
```

The `AttributeError` is because `sheets` is a `property` of the `writer` instance. If you're unfamiliar with it, [here is a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work-in-python).

In shorter terms, the exception is raised because `sheets` cannot be modified in the way you're trying. However, you can do this:

```py
# use the `.update` method
writer.sheets.update(dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets))
```

That will move us past the the `AttributeError`, but we'll hit a `ValueError` a couple lines down:

```py
reader = pd.read_excel("Resultados.xlsx")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\StackOverflow\answer.py", line 26, in <module>
    reader = pd.read_excel("Resultados.xlsx")
  ...
  File "...\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1656, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.
```

Do what the error message says and supply an argument to the `engine` parameter

```py
reader = pd.read_excel("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
```

And now we're back to your original `zipfile.BadZipFile` exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\StackOverflow\answer.py", line 26, in <module>
    reader = pd.read_excel("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
  ...
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 1334, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

After a bit of toying, I noticed that the `Resultados.xlsx` file could not be opened manually after running this line:

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
```

[image: excel error message]

So I reordered some of the steps in your code:

```py
    # run before initializing the ExcelWriter
    reader = pd.read_excel("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")

    book = load_workbook("Resultados.xlsx")

    # the old way
    # writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")

    with pd.ExcelWriter("Resultados.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets.update(dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets))

        df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader)+1)
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
filepath = r'Resultados.xlsx'
with pd.ExcelWriter(
        filepath,
        engine='openpyxl',
        mode='a',
        if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    reader = pd.read_excel(filepath)
    df.to_excel(
        writer,
        startrow=reader.shape[0] + 1,
        index=False,
        header=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to replace `writer.book` and `writer.sheets` with `writer.workbook` and `writer.worksheets` respectively.