# How to change Nan value to particular number in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
         DP 1    DP 2    DP 3     DP 4    DP 5    DP 6   DP 7    DP 8   DP 9    DP 10
OP 1     2.33    1.711   1.218   1.046   1.150   1.025   1.046   1.092  nan      -   
OP 2     3.043   1.691   1.362   1.174   1.067   1.048   1.051   1.059      
OP 3     4.054   1.717   1.238   1.132   1.068   1.056   1.045          
OP 4     3.014   1.748   1.327   1.103   1.093   1.116              
OP 5     2.798   1.862   1.241   1.242   1.148                  
OP 6     3.973   1.589   1.553   1.161                      
OP 7     3.372   1.552   1.458                          
OP 8     3.359   1.871                              
OP 9     3.494                                  
OP 10
```

this is the dataframe DF1 ;

```
for ele in DF1:
    x = ele+2.0
print(x)
```

this will give the output:

```
         DP 1     DP 2    DP 3    DP 4    DP 5    DP 6    DP 7    DP 8   DP 9   DP 10
OP 1     4.33    3.711   3.218   3.046   3.150   3.025   3.046   3.092    nan    -   
OP 2     5.043   3.691   3.362   3.174   3.067   3.048   3.051   3.059      
OP 3     6.054   3.717   3.238   3.132   3.068   3.056   3.045          
OP 4     5.014   3.748   3.327   3.103   3.093   3.116              
OP 5     4.798   3.862   3.241   3.242   3.148                  
OP 6     5.973   3.589   3.553   3.161                      
OP 7     5.372   3.552   3.458                          
OP 8     5.359   3.871                              
OP 9     5.494                                  
OP 10
```

But i Need Output like :

```
         DP 1     DP 2   DP 3     DP 4    DP 5    DP 6    DP 7    DP 8   DP 9   DP 10
OP 1     4.33    3.711   3.218   3.046   3.150   3.025   3.046   3.092   2.0     -   
OP 2     5.043   3.691   3.362   3.174   3.067   3.048   3.051   3.059      
OP 3     6.054   3.717   3.238   3.132   3.068   3.056   3.045          
OP 4     5.014   3.748   3.327   3.103   3.093   3.116              
OP 5     4.798   3.862   3.241   3.242   3.148                  
OP 6     5.973   3.589   3.553   3.161                      
OP 7     5.372   3.552   3.458                          
OP 8     5.359   3.871                              
OP 9     5.494                                  
OP 10
```

that means if i add nan to number then it should give the respective number.

Comment: `df.fillna(0)`?

Comment: No. It will give problem in further calculations. Is there any other solution?

Comment: are you looking for `df1 + 2`?

Comment: Yes!! Like if calculation happens between Nan and number then it should return number. For example nan + 2.0 then it should fill with 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
for ele in DF1:
    for ind,val in ele:
        if np.isnan(val):
            ele[ind] = 2.0
        else:
            ele[ind] = val+2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
data = [[1,10],[2,12],[3,13],[4,10],[5,12],[np.nan,13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b'],dtype=float)
for element in df['a']:
    if(element >= 0):
        x = element + 2.0
    else:
        x = 2.0
    print(x)
```

Easy Way:

```
df.fillna(2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply redefine addition so that `x+nan` evaluates to `x`, but that's rather dangerous. Safer is to define a custom function:

```
def nan_sum(a,b):
    if not a:
       return b
    if not b:
       return a
    return a+b
```

Then you can apply it to the dataframe: `DF1.applymap(lambda x: nan_sum(x,2.0))`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [`np.nan_to_num()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) function which is specifically designed to replace `nan`s with zeros.  Its default behavior is to replace `nan`s with `0.0`.

```
import numpy as np

df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan_to_num(x)+2)
```