# Appending to a sheet in Excel creates a new sheet instead of appending

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to use this code to append a dataframe to an existing sheet in Excel, but instead of appending the new data to it, it creates a new sheet.  Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as op

df = ['normal_dataframe']

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=False, index=False)
```

'test.xlsx' has a 'Sheet1', but when the file is appended, theres 2 sheets. 'Sheet1' and 'Sheet11'.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas

Comment: I found that post as well.  When i tried that method, it gives me a BadZipFile error that is a known bug with this type of work.  The code above works great, it just creates a new sheet instead of appending to the one specified.

Comment: You need to bind the workbook to the ExcelWriter object.

Comment: Can you please explain?  I'm not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

One approach with COM:

```
import win32com.client

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

path = r'c:\Users\Alex20\Documents\test.xlsx'
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(path)
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("E9:F10").Value = [[9,9],[10,10]]
wb.Close(True)
xl.Quit()
```

Comment: If I use 'w', it overwrites everything in that sheet, I need it to be added to the sheet specified.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that this was Linux.