# Unable to 'append' data to existing sheets in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have two sets of data which I want to append in different excel sheets using python.

I tried the following code but it actually writes a new sheet ex: education and experience, education1 and experience1.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('profile.xlsx',engine='openpyxl', mode = 'a') as writer:
    df_experience.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'experience', index = False)
    df_education.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'education', index = False)
```

what can i do to 'append' data to existing sheets?

Comment: You mean that you'r spreadsheet already has two sheets called _experience_ and _education_??

Comment: @ARK1375 Yes, I want to add more data to the already existing spreadsheets

Comment: Use the `startrow` flag and see if it helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas This answer helped^^^^