# Python appending dataframe to exsiting excel file and sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a question about appending a dataframe to existing sheet on existing file.

I tried to write the code by myself

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('existingFile.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="existingSheet", startrow=writer.sheets["existingSheet"].max_row, index=False, header=False)
```

and this would cause an error

**ValueError: Sheet 'existingSheet' already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'.**

and I googled and found this function in here;

[Append existing excel sheet with new dataframe using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas/38075046#38075046)

and even with this function, it still causes the same error, even though i think this function prevents this exact error from what i think.

Could you please help?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems this function is broken in pandas 1.3.0 Just look at this [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) , when trying to append to existing sheet it will either raise an error, create a new one or replace it

> if_sheet_exists{‘error’, ‘new’, ‘replace’}, default ‘error’ How to
> behave when trying to write to a sheet that already exists (append
> mode only).
>
> error: raise a ValueError.
>
> new: Create a new sheet, with a name determined by the engine.
>
> replace: Delete the contents of the sheet before writing to it.
>
> New in version 1.3.0

The only solution is to downgrade pandas (1.2.3 is working for me)

```
pip install pandas==1.2.3
```

Answer (score 11):

I guess I am late to the party but

Add keyword **`if_sheet_exists='replace'`** to ExcelWriter like this

```
pd.ExcelWriter('existingFile.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace' )
```

Then you can use the latest version of pandas

Comment: For me this overwrites '(replace) content in the sheet. It doesn't append.

Answer (score 10):

Since [Pandas 1.4](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html), there is also an `'overlay'` option to `if_sheet_exists`.

Comment: not working `overlay` option for me

Comment: Which Pandas version do you use?

Comment: tried with pandas==1.4.0

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: No error. but it overwrites everytime

Comment: Added new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72868000/python-pandas-excelwriter-is-not-working-as-expected if you know, please answer

Comment: This approach worked for me with pandas `1.4.2`: `with pd.ExcelWriter(excelPath, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer: timeseries.to_excel(writer, timeseriesSheetName)`