# Python-pandas excelwriter is not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to append data on existing excel sheet using Pandas-ExcelWriter functionality.
As per [python official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html), `if_sheet_exists=overlay` : **Write contents to the existing sheet without removing the old contents.**

Code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', mode='w')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [100, 200, 300]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

**Output I am getting:** (overwriting new data instead of appending)

[image]

**Output I am expecting:**

[image]

**Version details:**

```
Python : 3.9.2
Pandas : pandas==1.4.3
openpyxl : openpyxl==3.0.10
xlsx : XlsxWriter==3.0.3
```

**Trials**:

1. Tried with `engine='xlsxwriter'` for append mode. but got `ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to ignore `xlswriter.

my approach would be as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30]})
df.to_excel('pandas_simple.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False) #saving initial dataframe to file


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [100, 200, 300]}) # new data

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('pandas_simple.xlsx') # open old file
ws = wb["Sheet1"] # assign sheet to work with or as below
# ws = wb.active
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    ws.append(row.values.tolist())

wb.save("pandas_simple.xlsx")
```

Comment: This is the best solution I've found for appending data seamlessly. xlswriter has been so troublesome. Thank you!