# Python DataFrame: How to find first empty row in Excel and output a Dataframe there using to_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

Lets say I have a single row Pandas Dataframe called `df` with the following structure:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | Sheep | Lizard |

No lets say I have an excel file called "Aged Data" with a sheet called `Sheet1`. On `Sheet1` there is a table of data that looks like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Zebra | Lepard |
| Fish | Bird | Elephant |

I would like to use the `to_excel()` function to find the file and then add the single row of data in `df` to the first blank row in the sheet in excel.  The dataframe and the table in excel have the same column names and they are in the same order. The output should be a table in excel that looks like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Zebra | Lepard |
| Fish | Bird | Elephant |
| Dog | Sheep | Lizard |

How could I add this functionality to the code below?

```
# Writing final table into Excel
destdir = os.path.join(r'\\filepath,'Aged Data.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(destdir, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: I have not checked it, but sounds like it should work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df # you already have it
df_excel = pd.read_excel('Aged Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

pd.concat([df, df_excel], axis=0).to_excel('output.xlsx')
```