# Python Pandas - import all CSV files in folder, only picking up 1 file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

Hello StackOverflow community!

Struggling new python person here.  I have code that did work, until I added more to it and I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong to screw it up.  I'm trying to import a file, read the file name, remove columns, reset the index, fill a column with the filename (I need that info later on) and then move on to the next file.

For some reason, it's only importing the LAST file in the folder.  I know I've done something wrong.

Any help would be very much appreciated

```
csvPath = "blahblah"

dfData = pd.DataFrame(['NTLogin', 'Date', '', 'FileName'])

for f in glob.glob(csvPath + "\*.csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        filename = (os.path.basename(f))
        df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,3]], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.upper()
        df = df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index()
        df['Filename'] = filename
        dfData = pd.concat([df, dfData], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I just answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654322/adding-data-to-an-existing-excel-table/71654898#71654898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is processing all the CSVs, when concatenating you are not using your base dataframe (`dfData`) and just using the the new dataframe (`df`).

Also considering the `Filename`, it will be overwritten everytime.
Have it at `df` to avoid this:

```
df['Filename'] = filename
dfData = pd.concat([dfData, df], ignore_index=True)
```

#### List method

as suggested by pyaj in the comments, you can also use lists to achieve the same thing.

It will look like this:

```py
csvPath = "blahblah"

df_list = []

for f in glob.glob(csvPath + "\*.csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        filename = (os.path.basename(f))
        df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,3]], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.upper()
        df = df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index()
        df['Filename'] = filename

        df_list.append(df)

dfData = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

You can also check the list to see if each individual dataframe is correct.

Comment: When I do it like that I get a name error: name 'dfData' is not defined

Comment: I assumed you already have `dfData` defined like `dfData = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'FileName'])` before entering the loop.

Comment: I got that part fixed, but it's still only pulling in one file - the last file.  Updated the original to my new code

Comment: To make sure if file is pulled at a `print(f)` to the loop and check the result.

Comment: Good sleuthing!  Yup, its pulling in all files, they aren't being added to the dataframe.  Okay... got it working with your help!  Thank you @farshad!