# pandas appending data works online for few rows

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

my script writes on each iteration to excel file from row 2. But I need it to append data each time under the last row.

code need to write new data in a bulk from the last row

code is below

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import pandas as pd

class plateScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapePlate'
    allowed_domains = ['dvlaregistrations.direct.gov.uk']

    def start_requests(self):
        df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
        columnA_values=df['PLATE']
        for row in columnA_values:
            global  plate_num_xlsx
            plate_num_xlsx=row
            base_url =f"https://dvlaregistrations.direct.gov.uk/search/results.html?search={plate_num_xlsx}&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto="
            url=base_url
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        itemList=[]
        for row in response.css('div.resultsstrip'):
            plate = row.css('a::text').get()
            price = row.css('p::text').get()
            if plate_num_xlsx==plate.replace(" ","").strip():
                item= {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": price.strip()}
                itemList.append(item)
                yield  item
            else:
                item = {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": "-"}
                itemList.append(item)
                yield item

        with pd.ExcelWriter('output_res.xlsx', mode='a',if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
            df_output = pd.DataFrame(itemList)
            df_output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='result', index=False, header=True)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(plateScraper)
process.start()
```

It writes data in bulks, I mean rewriting some kind of 12 rows every time not appending and going down. Strange, is not it? Would like to hear the reason and how to fix it to write up to down all data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append existing excel sheet with new dataframe using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas)

Comment: when I put it `df_output.to_excel("output_res.xlsx",mode='a',sheet_name="result",index=False,header=True)` it gives an error `return func(*args,**kwargs)`

Comment: You need to do something like - 
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',  mode='a') as writer: 
    df_output=pd.DataFrame(itemList)
    df_output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='result',index=False,header=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like -

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',  mode='a') as writer: 
    df_output=pd.DataFrame(itemList)
    df_output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='result',index=False,header=True)
```

Comment: My situtation is more like to create first, then append. In your code snippet it needs to be created first

Comment: It rewrites only 12 rows. These first 12 rows are changing everytime not more