# Updating python excel data in an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am actually a new to python , currently i am facing an issue of panda dataframe ... i have a loop which outputs me on certain conditions the name of a person/folder in each iteration , i want this output name to be immediately sent to the dataframe but what i get in the dataframe is only 1 single row having the output of last iteration and all previous iteration outputs gets over write ...
below is the code i am using 
i hope u will understand my problem and will help

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import csv
import dlib
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd
from skimage import  io
import face_recognition
from PIL import Image
with open("Data/train.csv","r") as facefeatures2:
    reader=csv.reader(facefeatures2)
    featureslist2=[]
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) != 0:
            featureslist2= featureslist2 +[row]

facefeatures2.close()
float_int2=[]
results=[]
for f2 in range(0,len(featureslist2)):
    float_int2 = float_int2 +[[float(str) for str in subarray] for subarray in [featureslist2[f2]]]
    csv2 = np.vstack(float_int2)
faces_folder_path = "Data/newcropped"
list = os.listdir(faces_folder_path) # dir is your directory path
number_files = len(list)
print (number_files)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_name11.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for loop in range(0,number_files):
    print("iteration ="+str(loop+1))
    unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(faces_folder_path + "/" + str(loop+1)+".jpg")
    cv2.imshow("test",unknown_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    #### --------------exception handling-----------####
    try:
        unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

    except  IndexError:
        print("--->image is not detectable")
        pass
        # ...........................#
    results = face_recognition.compare_faces(csv2, unknown_face_encoding)
    chunks=[results[x:x + 12] for x in range(0, len(results),12)] # splits "results" list into sublists of size 12
    dirpath = "Data/eachperson"
    fname = []
    fname = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir(dirpath))]
    counter = 0
    index=0
    for c in range (0,len(chunks)):
        if 'True' in str(chunks[c]):
            counter=counter+1
            index=c
            df = pd.DataFrame({'names': [fname[index]]})
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    if counter !=1 or counter ==0 :
           print("student is not present :(")
    else:
        print(str(fname[index])+" is present!!!")
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you initialise a dataframe list? Keep appending to the list, and only at the end, you should merge it into one big dataframe and write to it. `.to_excel` overwrites the excel file each time it writes, so calling it inside a loop is not a good idea unless you open it in append mode. But again, that is inefficient.

Try something like this:

```
df_list = []
for loop in range(0, number_files):
   ...

   for c in range (0,len(chunks)):
        if 'True' in str(chunks[c]):
            ...

            df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'names': [fname[index]]}))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_name11.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

---

If you, instead, want to rewrite on each iteration, you can also consider taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36450435/4909087).

Comment: thank you so very much it works , but it always have a column in dataframe written  0 all the way  ! can you please tell me why ?

Comment: @hamzayahya Cannot say without seeing your data. If it isn't a big problem, just open it in MS Excel and delete. Anyway, if it helps, you can mark this answer accepted. Cheers.

Comment: brother its just look creep that why i am asking it actually looks like [ 0 john present ]  then again in next row its like [ 0 pattrick present] i hope u understand ...

Comment: and also is there any way that code automatically generates date and time in front of each row against each name (i-e when its created)

Comment: @hamzayahya Try this: `pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')`

Comment: yes brother it works u r a savage ... cheers ... one last question is there anyway that this code automatically generates date and time in front of each row (i-e in front of each name ) as an additional column

Comment: @hamzayahya I would recommend you open another question, because that requires more code than I am willing to answer in comments :) Please mark accepted if it helped, and open a new question. Explain what is your current input and what is your expected output. I'd love to help, and it helps the community too.

Comment: if you dont mind please answer it here , this is what i am using as you know from my above code to generate names and status column ....... df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'names': [fname[index]] , 'status': ['present']})) ..... now i want date and time in it also infront of these

Comment: @hamzayahya The problem is I can't understand what you want. You will need to explain it in more details and I would rather you did that in another question, that's it.

Comment: How would you get the date and time? Where would it come from?